# Is there any way to "Fit Layer to Canvas Size" in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

So after doing a bit of research, I am unable to find a command anywhere in Gimp 2.8.22 which will stretch my layer size to the size of my canvas, essentially the opposite of **Image->Fit Canvas to Layers**.

Any thoughts would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Essentially the opposite of Image -> Fit Canvas to Layers

1. Image -> Canvas, followed by
2. Layer -> Layer to Image Size

There are also a number of other solutions in [image resizing - Resize layer to fit canvas - Gimp - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018007/resize-layer-to-fit-canvas-gimp)

Comment: Not sure when this changed but "Layer to Image Size" is now "Image-sized layers" option in 'Resize layers:' dropdown.

Comment: True, but "Fit" ("... STRETCH my layer ...") means that the layer contents should be SCALED to the canvas/image size. "Layer to Image Size" CROPS layer content.

Answer (score 2):

If it's done after an `Image>Canvas size`, remember than resizing layers is already an option of `Image>Canvas size`.

Otherwise, use `Layer>Layer to image size` (that will crop the Layer instead if the layer is larger than the canvas, or will even extend it at places and crop it elsewhere if the layer is offset from the canvas).

Comment: True, but not what the question asks. "Fit" means that the layer contents should be SCALED to the canvas/image size. THIS answer (as it mentions) CROPS layer content.

Comment: See the [`ofn-autoscale-layer` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/), then. It scales the layer to the scale of the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Menu: Layer > Scale layer

Gimp 2.10.32

Comment: CLARIFICATION: You'll have to MANUALLY enter the canvas dimensions into the Scale Layer dialog. (The dialog is initialized with the layer's current dimensions.) The question asks if there is "FIT to canvas", which would automatically scale to canvas size.

Comment: (This is still better than the older answers, which do not SCALE one LAYER's contents.)

Comment: There seems to be lack of clarity on this original post.  I interpret Layer from the OP, is meaning not just the Layer in Gimp, but whatever is on that layer, to also be resized.  If that is the case, then this feel like a suitable answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is incorrect - the correct way to scale an image in so that it fits accurately to the canvas size is as follows

1. lets say for example your canvas is 6000k x 6000k and your image is 2048 x 2048.
2. the image is therefore smaller than the canvas - to scale it so it fits neatly with the borders of your canvas
3. click on your image - then select the scale scale tool.
4. scale the image to the same size as the canvas.
5. typically your image is now the same size as the canvas but it will not be correctly aligned.
6. to align the enlarged image to the canvas select the align tool from the tools menu - Tools - transform tools - align (it says tap q as a short cut - but this does not always work)
7. once one have selected the align tool - click again on you image - you will now see a range of align too option in your side menus and you can choose the centre align tool to bring your image flush to the canvas margins.

Comment: This scales the IMAGE, not a selected LAYER.